# How can I test for a valid index

Tags: .net, xml, xpath

It is legal to have XPath that is "/root/name[bogus = 'dave']" where the bogus node does not exist. It will return null on a SelectSingleNode.

But XPath that is "/root/name[5]" where there are only 4 name nodes under root throws an exception. (At least it does in .NET).

What is a good way to test and see if an index value is valid?

thanks - dave

Comment: Please show us your code that results in an exception.

Comment: (because I can do `var x = XDocument.Parse("<root><a /></root>");` and then `var n = x.XPathSelectElement("/root/a[5]");` and I get `null`, not an exception)

Comment: Yes there should not be (and is not) a exception if xspth does not found something. Looks like you do not test if the return is not null.

Comment: What exception does it throw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XPath 1.0, you could evaluate this XPath expression:

```
bool(/root/name[5])
```

which will return true if the `<root>` element has a fifth `<name>` child.

But as others have said, XPath itself should not raise an exception for trying to access a node that doesn't exist. However, the .NET library may raise an exception if you try to dereference a null value.